# How to write generic type and duck typing in the same function?

Tags: f#

How can I write like this (it has compile error)?

```ml
module T =
    let inline (|Id|) x =
        fun () -> (^a : (member Id: string) x)

    let inline id (Id f) = f()

    let inline test<'a> param =
        let aT = typeof<'a>.Name
        let idStr = id param
        sprintf "%s %s" aT idStr

    type C =
        { Name: string }
        with
        member __.Id = "1"

    let c = { Name = "abc" }

    let b = test<int> c
```

I want `test` function to receive generic type `'a` as I want to use the type in `let aT = typeof<'a>.Name`, and it also can receive type of `param` (statically resolved one) as I want to use the type in `let idStr = id param`.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I can't make it compiled.

Comment: Please tell us the exact error message you're getting. "it has compile error" isn't a particularly useful problem description for anyone. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure why this happens. Perhaps it's because you need to specify all type parameters explicitly, if you specify one? As I said, I don't know. However, adding another type parameter to the `test` function appears to do the trick:

```
module T =
    let inline (|Id|) x =
        fun () -> (^a : (member Id: string) x)

    let inline id (Id f) = f()

    let inline test<'a, ^b when ^b : (member Id: string)> (param: ^b) =
        let aT = typeof<'a>.Name
        let idStr = id param
        sprintf "%s %s" aT idStr

    type C =
        { Name: string }
        with
        member __.Id = "1"

    let c = { Name = "abc" }

    let b = test<int, _> c
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to only pass the generic type and let compiler infers the remaining statically resolved type. The only way to make compiler happy is passing all the types.

Comment: "Perhaps it's because you need to specify all type parameters explicitly, if you specify one?" --> Yes, that's exactly it. Plus if you specify the parameters then you must specify all the member constraints too.